# Is the Assassin's Creed 2016 movie considered canon in the game universe?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

Is the 2016 [Assassin's Creed movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2094766/) starring Michael Fassbender as Aguilar de Nerha considered Canon in the Assassin's Creed games universe?

Comment: This might be better suited for [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), given it’s asking about the movie

Comment: @Wondercricket Still answerable, Origins provides a fairly straightforward (if self-indulgent) connection or two to the movie.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a movie, not a game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, yes. The following email can be found in Assassins Creed: Origins, which references the movie's unorthodox Animus design found only in the movie:

[image: Email]

[Source](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1718379/how-the-assassins-creed-movie-connects-to-the-new-game)

Comment: There are points in the history of Aguillar that they just ignore the Altair's Chronicles history.